# Qgis 2.10-kml is not a valid or recognized data source

Tags: qgis, kml, import

After upgrade from Qgis 2.8, importing the kml format doesn't work. The Kml file is not problem, because it works well on other computers. I tried to reinstall Qgis, but the problem is still here...Any ideas?

Comment: If you open the OSGEO4W shell (or a terminal on Linux) and type `ogrinfo --formats`, do you have a line with `"KML" (read/write)`?

Comment: Yes, I have this line. I also tried to convert kml to shp via terminal: ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output3.shp input3.kml and got error:FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `*.kml' with the following drivers.

Comment: Maybe it contains elements that the driver can not transform. If you save a shapefile to kml, can you open that with QGIS, or transform it back to shapefile with ogr2ogr? Which operating system are you working on? Can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: What do you get with `ogrinfo input3.kml`? Check also GDAL version with `ogrinfo --version`.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 17.2. For example, I converted SHP on this link http://www.mappinghacks.com/data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.2.zip to KML in Qgis and KML was processed ok but I can't open this KML in Qgis again. And transformation back to SHP with ogr2ogr failed. ogrinfo input3.kml-->Unable to open datasource `input3.kml' with the following drivers. ogrinfo --version-->GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10

Comment: Strange, it works for me on Windows XP, both QGIS 2.8 and 2.10 can read the kml created by QGIS or ogr2ogr. Driver is KML (not libkml). I will test on Ubuntu later.

Comment: So re-run the tests on lubuntu 15.04 with a fresh QGIS 2.10.1 installation. Again no problems, Driver is `LIBKML` in GDAL 1.11.2. On converting to kml, I get a message `Longitude 180.000002 has been modified to fit into range [-180,180]`; and that results in some artefacts in Siberia. Can you upload your kml as well?

Comment: File is uploaded on this link:http://www.filedropper.com/test_13. A week ago I migrated from Linux Mint 17.1 to 17.2. Maybe is problem here.

Comment: Linux Mint 17.2 is not a problem. I started Linux Mint 17.2 on VirtualMachine and opening kml in Qgis worked fine.